# React hooks call setState with same primitive value still cause re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I find that when I define a state with the value '1',

and set the state with the value '2' every time when I click a button,

the **first two** times will cause re-render

reproduce demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-brattain-ys11d

code: using react@17 without strict mode

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState("1");
  console.log("render", a);
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setA("2");
      }}
    >
      {a}
    </button>
  );
}

// log:
// render 1
// render 2
// render 2
```

I can understand the first re-render because the state changed to '2' from '1',

but I don't understand the second re-render

Comment: for your code there is no `2` number or increment code. Then how you get the `render 2`

Comment: What's wrong with that, looks everything works fine. It renders once. To check it clearly set `a's` initial value integer 1 instead of string then increase that value by `1` when click the button. e.g: `setA(a +1)`

Comment: Also, assuming your actual code does have a simple increment functionality unlike the code in your question, and you're just getting 2 renders every state change, it might be from strict mode: https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/

Comment: @prasanth sorry about my typo, I've updated both my code snippet and the link, open the codesandbox link, click the button many times will append two "render 2" log in console

Comment: @Jayce444 I am not running the app inside `<React.StrictMode />`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this explains the anomaly very well:

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)

> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo

Note the last paragraph. This is quoted directly from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update).

Answer (score 0):

I think something missing in the code. I checked on my end. it's working fine as per our expectations.

Thanks

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1);
  console.log("render", a);
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setA(a + 1);
      }}
    >
      {a}
    </button>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: hello, I've updated my question, I am not trying to increment the state value, I am trying the set the same value every time I click the button, but the `console.log` get run more time than I expected